# Is it safe to rely on Function.prototype.toString?

Tags: javascript, function, cross-browser, tostring

Is it safe to rely on `Function.prototype.toString` to return a string that will parse as a valid javascript function (for user-defined functions)?

Are there any commonly-used javascript engines that deviate from the norm as far as how they represent function objects in string form?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379875/can-javascript-get-a-function-as-text), but I'm not sure if it's asking the same thing. I don't care if the formatting is exactly the same in all implementations or whatever, I'm more worried about some minified js engine just stripping out the whole function body...

Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650593/javascript-using-tostring-on-a-function-object-to-read-text-content), but not closely related enough to have a satisfying answer for this question.

Comment: See http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/ and http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's safe since it's a standard. Every serious engine would do. That's also what my project [Jscex](https://github.com/JeffreyZhao/jscex) is based on. It works for all the browsers (even the legacy IE6) and Node.js. I do this kind of things for year. :)

Comment: Sounds scexy. I am exploring iframe sandboxes :) I'm mostly worried about phones, embedded, weird IE security modes, stuff like that. Just want to look at some tests or studies or live use-cases that are not prototype.js for reassurance i guess.

Comment: Well, I've tested [this (one of Jscex's samples)](http://files.zhaojie.me/jscex/samples/async/sorting-animations.html?quick) in Windows Phone, iOS, Android phones, they all works.

Comment: Jscex looks pretty interesting. Is there any reason you're using eval instead of the Function constructor? I think the Function constructor is supposed to be significantly faster. That's very cool though. +1 for Jscex ;)

Comment: `eval` is easy to use and keep everything in current context (scope, closure). and each function would only be applied **once** when the script loads. Also, `eval` is a dev tools, which would gone in production after AOT.

Comment: i see, so the production site would have pre-compiled code instead of the eval'd code on the test site. I will have to look into Jscex more, it sounds like it could be a big time saver

Comment: Thanks, you can contact me via the email if you meet any problem. The doc in github is a little bit old (but most of the things and the big pictures are correct) since I'm focusing on local community and writing Chinese docs & articles. The samples are always work so they're good references.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that eval'd code will take on the current scope and the Function constructor will only take on the global scope.

```
function createClosure() {
    var x = 20,
        y = 10;

    // Doesn't know what x & y are
    var fn = new Function("return x + y");

    // Evaluates normally
    var result = eval("x + y");
}
```

Comment: I suppose that's worth noting, but I was really trying to figure out if all implementations supported a Function#toString that could be rehydrated. Turns out at least some versions of Opera Mobile don't support it.